# I need help making the backend for a little gui I am making

Tags: python, tkinter

It is supposed to print out the book information of "The Sea" by John Tablet but it keeps giving an error giving the following error:

```
    cr.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title text, author text, year integer, isbn integer)")
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

Can someone identify the issue? Here is the code:

```
def connect():
    con=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
    cr=con.cursor
    cr.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title text, author text, year integer, isbn integer)")
    con.commit()
    con.close()
   
def insert(title,author,year,isbn):
    con=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
    cr=con.cursor
    cr.execute("INSERT INTO book VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?)",(title,author,year,isbn))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
    
def view():
    con=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
    cr=con.cursor
    cr.execute("SELECT * FROM book")
    rows=cur.fetchall()
    con.close()
    return rows
    
    
    
connect()
insert("The Sea", "John Tablet", 1918, 193123132)
print(view())
```

Comment: Did you mean `cr = con.cursor()`?

Answer (score 2):

You missed to call the cursor initiation function instead you have the function reference in your variable cr.

Replace

```
 cr=con.cursor
```

with

```
 cr=con.cursor()
```

A small piece of advice. if you read the error, it clearly mentions that cr is a builtin_function_or_method which means that it is a function and not a cursor. So, by reading the errors we can identify and fix all our issues.

Comment: Radhakirshnan thanks

Comment: @mkrieger1 should receive the credit!:)

Comment: So... this particular question was resolved as a typo (which is why it was closed). The comment, pointing out the typo prior to you posting the same thing as an answer, was really all that was needed.